# flutter, how to wrap barcode and qr code in the same container?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make the barcode above the qrcode and I will like to make them in the same container, how should I edit it?

Thanks Alot!

```
  body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                child: SfBarcodeGenerator(
                  value: 'www.syncfusion.com',
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: mFillColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  border: Border.all(color: mBorderColor, width: 1),
                ),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 350,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(90.0),
                  child: QrImage(
                    data: 'This is a simple QR code',
                    version: QrVersions.auto,
                    gapless: false,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

What this code will show:
[image]

The effect that I want:
[image]

Comment: If you mean one of them infornt of the other, use `Stack`.

Comment: @huthaifa , i mean not on the infront, but inside the container and abovev the qrcode

Comment: post a picture of how it looks now and how you want it to look.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad posted

Comment: I think you need a stack, try replacing the word `column` with `stack`. And reverse the order of the objects, put the barcode second.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you do this task. First you design a parent `Container` and then use a `Column` widget which contains two `sizedBox` as a children one is for barcode and second is for QrCode. Just like this

```
Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: 250,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
          ),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                child: SfBarcodeGenerator(
                  value: 'www.syncfusion.com',
                ),
              ),
              const Text(
                "2810 1102 0604 3155 4434 2047",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 150,
                child: QrImage(
                  data: 'This is a simple QR code',
                  version: QrVersions.auto,
                  gapless: false,
                ),
              ),
              const Text(
                "Any text here",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

[image]